# Does Windows 8 cache your account password?

Tags: windows-8

I want to install Windows 8 on my notebook. Because of this, I wanted to know if

- Windows 8 caches your Microsoft account password
- and how long

because I will not have internet access everywhere I go.

How does Windows 8 handle this?

Comment: Windows stores the password exactly like it stores a local account's password. **Besides when you don't have internet access use local account**  In addition this is easy enough to confirm yourself by disabling your internet before you logging into your notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure for how long, but Windows 8 does cache the Microsoft account password. I use my Microsoft account to log in all the time, and I have never been unable to log in because of a lack of Internet connection.

Comment: This is a better answer as it more clearly answers exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose not to use a Microsoft account when you install Windows 8, and have an offline password just like in previous versions of Windows.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/set-up

> If you’d still rather sign in with a user name and password, click **Sign in without a Microsoft account.**

It's also possible to switch between account types if you've linked a Microsoft account but need to be able to log in without an internet connection: http://dottech.org/87239/windows-8-how-to-switch-between-local-offline-account-and-microsoft-online-account-and-vice-versa/

Comment: This isn't necessary - you can in fact sign on with your MS account credentials when you're offline, it keeps some info locally for a period of time.  (I don't know specifics.)

Comment: So, when the data is cached for longer time, this is really not necessary, but it might be useful at some point. +1